# OS Uninstaller killed Windows 7, can't boot

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-7

I used OS Uninstaller started from a live cd to remove old tries to install Ubuntu and Zorin(and 2 already installed Ubuntu distros), but now when I try to boot, the PC tells me there's no boot device. My Windows 7 Install and Restore CD's don't want to boot. I checked the filesystem on my HDD, and Windows files are OK. How to make it start? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair to help you restore the ability to boot

Answer (score 0):

Use Boot-Repair's Recommended Repair as described here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#Recommended_repair . Indicate the URL that will appear if any doubt.